# Graphing logarithmic Equations and there inverses

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Graph the following: y=log_(3)(x+2) and find the inverse function, graph it, and find the x-intercept, y-intercept, asymptote line, domain and range. I literally have no idea what I am doing on this problem and I have a test in two days over this kind of material. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to graph the original function for you, but I can find the inverse and graph that.

We want to find the inverse of:
$$f(x)=\log_3(x+2)$$
First, change $f(x)$ to $y$.
$$y=\log_3(x+2)$$
Swap $x$ and $y$, and solve for $y$.
$$x=\log_3(y+2)$$
Remember that if $\log_a(b)=c$, then $a^c=b$.
$$y+2=3^x$$
$$y=3^x-2$$
The last step is to change $y$ to $f^{-1}(x)$
$$f^{-1}(x)=3^x-2$$
That is the equation of the inverse.

There is an asymptote of this inverse at $y=-2$. How do I get this, you ask? Imagine that $x$ gets closer and closer to $-\infty$. What does $3^x-2$ equal, then? It would equal $-\dfrac{1}{3^{\infty}}-2$. The first term is pretty much equal to $0$, so the answer is $-2$. We say that $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}3^x-2=-2$. This means that as $x$ tends toward $-\infty$, the value of $3^x-2$ (which is actually $f^{-1}(x)$) gets closer and closer to $-2$.

To find the $x$ intercept, let $f^{-1}(x)=0$ (because the $x$ intercept occurs when the $y$-coordinate is $0$).
$$3^x-2=0$$
$$3^x=2$$
$$\log(3^x)=\log(2)$$
$$x\log(3)=\log(2)$$
$$x=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}$$
That is your $x$-intercept. To find the $y$-intercept, set $x$ to be $0$.
$$3^0-2=1-2=-1$$
The $y$-intercept is $-1$.

The domain should be apparent to you: $\{x\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. The range is just a little more complicated. We know that the graph is always going to be above $y=-2$ from the asymptote, so that means $y>-2$. As the $x$ value gets larger and larger, the $y$ value gets larger and larger as well. $y$ goes up all the way to $\infty$. Therefore the range is $\{y\mid y>-2, \ y\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Graphing it is something you can do. The $x$-intercept is when $y=0$, i.e., $\log_3(x+2)=0$. The $y$-intercept is when $x=0$, i.e., $\log_3(2)$. The asymptote line is the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}y$. The domain is when the function is actually defined, in this case $(-2,\infty)$. The range is $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Okay thank you, and how do I find the inverse function?

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Find an expression for $x$ in terms of $y$. In this, case, exponentiate to get $3^y-2=x\implies f^{-1}(x)=3^x-2$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! And last question, would the vertical asymptote be a horizontal asymptote in the inverse function?

Comment: @IlaIsabelle What do you think?

Comment: I think it would but I am doubting myself if I have it mixed up or not. It could be the inverse function has the vertical asymptote.

Comment: @IlaIsabelle A vertical asymptote occurs when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\pm\infty$. You are confusing yourself.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you!